# how can i use the same SELECT form over

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, html-select

I have a HTML page that has a table with 6 columns, and about 70 rows. In column3 i have a SELECT drop down list in all 70 rows that has the same list. I'm used to C# and java where I can just make a class and then reference that class over and over again, but i am super new to HTML.

My options for this are somewhat open, as this eventually is going to be hosted on my apache server at work, and my team will use this form instead of the excel sheet that i made forever ago. basically i want to use mysql instead of the excel sheets as I can run queryies and so forth. I have mantisbt installed already on said apache server. I mention that because mantis is made in PHP. I've read a few times that PHP might be a better answer than making this strictly in HTML..and since i have to communicate with mysql that i should go this route anyway. The few pages that i saw of php (from looking into the mantis files) it has many similar tags as HTML, so i figure that I could mock up a HTML page, then copy and paste it into my php page and make the few small changes to make it work. am I being stupid about this? I've also heard that javascript runs native on most browsers now, and my teams will be using either IE8 or Chrome as we all have win xp.

My question in the end is...what is the best way to get this same combo box in all 70 of my rows that will be an easy transistion to PHP when I make the switch.

Comment: Too Long! Some code will be fine, if not, give some spaces!

Comment: you can make a php class to reuse as often as needed

Comment: somehow i don't think anyone will ever be happy with the length of a post, either it is too long, or too short. Well sorry but i'd rather have too much information then not enough. I hate it when i have to post 10 times to clarify what I meant.

Comment: thank you for that bit of info, I will look into PHP then and see about using PHP's combo box instead of HTML's

Answer (score 0):

you said that you have a table of 70 rows and six columns you said that in column three you have a dropdown of options first create an array with those options(let say $optary) later you can construct your table as shown below

```
<table>
<th>1</th><th>2</th><th>3</th><th>4</th><th>5</th><th>6</th>
<td>data 1</td>
<td>data 2</td>
<td><select name='optionval'><?php foreach($optary as $val){?>
<option value='<?php echo $val?>'><?php echo $val;?></option>
<?php }?></select></td>
<td>data 4</td>
<td>data 5</td>
<td>data 6</td>
</table>
```

you can use this in another array or in any where if you loop above block for 70 times same dropdown list will appear in all rows.

Comment: Yeah, i've seen this before, and looks like kind of what i want. Thank you for your information

Comment: if you are constructing a table with database fetched values put the above block in to that loop and replace all the static data with dynamic data

Answer (score 0):

Okay here the deal. First of all, you are not going to accomplish anything with HTML. It's just markup, it does not do anything. You need to get interested in Jquery if you want to pull data from a remote server. Your focus should be in a process called Ajax.

Next you will need the man in the middle php to retrieve stuff from a server using real SQL queries and then return it to the Jquery to manipulate the DOM (the page). Can you do this yourself? Sure. Would I recommend it? Absolutely not. Have a look at this [plugin](http://datatables.net/) here that handles all your front end and back end needs for a dynamic table.

Comment: thank you for that input. I will look into that plugin. If it looks like a better/easier option i might use that and select your answer. Thank you.

Comment: Misleading information. A datatable does not save you from writing the back end codes. You still will need to write the model and controller. It just saves you from writing the table and passing criterias. 

Jquery and ajax is overkill in this case. A simple plain php array can solve this.

Comment: Please don't teach people to use backwards methods for solving problems. Jquery is exactly what he needs perform Ajax commands to retrieve information. You dont think so? You are dead wrong and I dont appreciate muddling correct information with inappropriate misinformation. No one said he only needs a database. Just stop, please.

Comment: Anyway, Snyder, that plugin I linked you to has both the php and the Jquery to handle your task. The Usage is simple, make an html table, copy paste the jqeury code given in their documentation and upload the php file they provide you. You will need a database table to pull info from and it does the rest. Good luck.